# Chrome DevTool Emulation For iPhone showing Extra Blackspace at the top

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In chrome Developer Emulation Tool, When Emulating the iPhone6, I am getting the extra black space at the top?

Is it the default behaviour or it is indicating the navigation bar for safari?.

Thanks in advance for any comment. see the screenshot.

[image]